# How come the discount amount textbox and total price aren't calculating right?

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-4.6

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XEx02Quotation
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
       
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {
                int SalesPrice = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
                // When a user inputs an integer, I want it to be able to handle input of fractions
                // without getting an exception error. 



                // If a user inputs a whole number or fractional number (like 20.25), it should be able
                // to handle it.
                double DiscountPercentage = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text);
                

                double discountValue = this.CalculateDiscountValue(SalesPrice, DiscountPercentage);
                double TotalPrice = this.TotalPriceCalculate(SalesPrice, discountValue);
                Label1.Text = discountValue.ToString("c");
                Label2.Text = TotalPrice.ToString("c"); 
            
            }
        }
        protected double CalculateDiscountValue(int SalesPrice, double DiscountPercentage)
        {
           double discountAmount = SalesPrice * DiscountPercentage;
            return discountAmount; 
        }

        protected double TotalPriceCalculate(int SalesPrice, double discountAmount)
        {
            double TotalPrice = SalesPrice - discountAmount;
            return TotalPrice; 
        }


    }
        
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="XEx02Quotation.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Price quotation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 54%;
            height: 213px;
        }
        .auto-style15 {
            width: 114px;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style16 {
            width: 114px;
        }
        .auto-style17 {
            width: 114px;
            height: 28px;
        }
        .auto-style18 {
            width: 193px;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style20 {
            width: 193px;
            height: 28px;
        }
        .auto-style21 {
            width: 193px;
        }
        .auto-style22 {
            margin-left: 12px;
        }
        .auto-style23 {
            margin-left: 16px;
        }
        .auto-style25 {
            width: 193px;
            height: 5px;
        }
        .auto-style26 {
            width: 114px;
            height: 5px;
        }
        .auto-style27 {
            width: 143px;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style28 {
            width: 143px;
            height: 5px;
        }
        .auto-style29 {
            width: 143px;
        }
        .auto-style30 {
            width: 143px;
            height: 28px;
        }
        .auto-style31 {
            width: 143px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .auto-style32 {
            width: 193px;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .auto-style33 {
            width: 114px;
            height: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        
        <h1>Price quotation</h1>
        
        <br />
        <br />
        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style27">Sales Price</td>
                <td class="auto-style18">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style23" Width="173px" Font-Bold="True"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style15"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style27"></td>
                <td class="auto-style18"></td>
                <td class="auto-style15"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style27">Discount percent</td>
                <td class="auto-style18">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style22" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style15"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style28">Discount amount</td>
                <td class="auto-style25">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style26"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style27"></td>
                <td class="auto-style18"></td>
                <td class="auto-style15"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style30">Total price</td>
                <td class="auto-style20">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style17"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style31">
                    </td>
                <td class="auto-style32"></td>
                <td class="auto-style33"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style29">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Calculate" Width="90px" />
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style21">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style16">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

when I input the sales price in the textbox as a fraction (like 120.99) and enter an int number or double (like 15 or 20.2) into the discount percentage textbox, the discount amount and total price doesn't calculate right? Do I need to do explicit conversions with my variables? I am so confused. Here is code for ASP.NET web form in my web application. I am currently working within my Default.aspx.cs (C#) file (and I also have a Default.aspx file too).

Comment: For any monetary calculations you oght to use decimal, not double. Also: 'Not right' is not a helpful problem description!

Comment: @TaW So you mean change some of  my variable types to decimal? Like the discount percentage?

Comment: This is always recommended but since I don't know what goes wrong, there may be other issues as well.

Comment: @TaW Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: What is the expected output for your inputs?  I noticed that you are just multiplying discount percentage and sales price. From your inputs, discount value calculation shall have division by 100 to calculate the value. Also, think about rounding off strategy

Comment: @Sunil Singhal Everytime I input a fraction into the Sales Price textbox (like 120.99) and a fraction for the discount percentage textbox (15.3), it incorrecly calculates the discount amount and total price.

Comment: What is that wrong value and what correct value do you expect?

Comment: @Sunil Singhal For example, when I input 120.99 in the sales price textbox and 15.5 in the the discount percentage textbox, the discount amount should show 18.75 and the total price should be 102.24

Comment: @Sunil Singhal Are you still here?

Comment: @Vikash.777 Do you think you could help me out?

Comment: @User445555 you are missing division by 100 while calculating discount. Replace `SalesPrice * DiscountPercentage;` with `SalesPrice * DiscountPercentage\ 100`. Have Rounding off strategy as well. Please check my previous comment

Comment: @ Sunil Singhal Adding \ 100 to the discountAmount calculation did nothing except give me an exception.

Comment: It should have been `/ 100`

Comment: @Deolus  It still gives me an exception when I try to input fractions (like 120.99 into sales price textbox or 12.4 into the discount percentage textbox). Would be better if I change my variables into all decimal types?

Comment: @Deolus It only does what what it's supposed to do when I enter  int numbers in the sales price (like 120) textbox and double  numbers (like 0.25) into the discount percentage textbox, but I want it to work with fractions like 150.32 in the sales price textbox and 20 (different integers) in the discountpercentage textbox

Comment: @Plutonix Do you think you can show another example with how the inputs can be calculated correctly?

Comment: All numeric values **are not integers**.  If a variable is to contain a fractional amount such as `1.2`, `.25` or `3.14` it needs to be a double, single or decimal.  Decimal would be appropriate for money amounts.  Programming 101 and is what the splendid answer posted is conceptually trying to tech you

Comment: @Plutonix Should I just change my variables to all decimal types then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments and in [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw)'s answer, you should be using `decimal` instead of `int` and the total price calculation misses *division by 100*. I have put everything together.

The click handler should be modified as follows:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            decimal salesPrice;
            decimal discount;

            if (decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out salesPrice))
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out discount))
                {
                    decimal discountValue = this.CalculateDiscountValue(salesPrice, discount);
                    decimal totalPrice = this.TotalPriceCalculate(salesPrice, discount);

                    Label1.Text = discountValue.ToString("c");
                    Label2.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the helper methods as follows:

```
protected decimal CalculateDiscountValue(decimal salesPrice, decimal discountPercentage)
 {
    return salesPrice * discountPercentage / 100m;
 }

protected decimal TotalPriceCalculate(decimal salesPrice, decimal discountAmount)
 {
    return salesPrice - discountAmount;
 }
```

Comment: @ashin-I actually figured it out yesterday night. I changed all of data types to double, but when I checked my web form, it still wasn't doing what I wanted to do. Then I realized that it wasn't the code; it was the configuration setting of range validator set to 'String' instead of 'Double' in the properties window of Visual Studio. Once I changed that, my web form calculated like it was supposed to!